# css of end of words in the span is not correct

Tags: html, css

i have a table that have one row and two column , in the second "td" i have a lot of separated word so i put them in a "span" one by one
 possible to have a long of sequential span element and i want to set a scroll-x
spans are inline but end of word is sticking form, for example:"دفترچه" is correct but "دفترچهـ" is not 
when i changed display to table-cell seems like correct but i miss some other style sheet like as margin
what is my mistake and how can i to fix it?

https://jsfiddle.net/L44vmbh8

```
*{
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
direction:rtl;
}

.item td div{
overflow-x: scroll;
width: 75vw;
height:55px;
}

.item td div span{
background-color: #00ff26;
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
display: inline;

}

.item>div{
max-width: 82vw;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
padding: 5px;

}
```

```
<div class="item">
        <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>نام:</td>
                <td><div><span>دفتر</span><span>دفترچه</span><span>دیوان</span><span>دفتر</span><span>دفترچه</span><span>دیوان</span><span>دفتر</span><span>دفترچه</span><span>دیوان</span><span>دفتر</span><span>دفترچه</span><span>دیوان</span><span>دفتر</span><span>دفترچه</span><span>دیوان</span><span>دفتر</span><span>دفترچه</span><span>دیوان</span><span>دفتر</span><span>دفترچه</span><span>دیوان</span><span>دفتر</span><span>دفترچه</span><span>دیوان</span><span>دفتر</span><span>دفترچه</span><span>دیوان</span></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i do not find the problem like u said... the html and the css in the jssfiddle looks good to me... i only add "valign='top' "  on the first column and everything looks ok.

Answer (score -1):

here is the screen shot after i modified ur html and css
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXq8o.jpg

updated:

i added  vertical align "Top" in the first column. As For reference u can visit the http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: @cyan thanks for answer and comment i see in the screen shot you used WebKit based browser and it is correct ! so i tested the first link and that is correct in a WebKit browser  too and it's maybe a Gecko bug i dont know in now , but try it by FireFox